# Regarding group notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, prime-numbers, notation, integers

I came across the following notation and couldn't make sense of it:
$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

What is this denoting? What are the elements of this set?

Comment: These are the integers modulo $p$. In general $G / H$ is the quotient group of $G$ modulo $H$, where $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: As a set $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ has for elements the cosets of $p\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I can’t believe this question got two downvotes

Comment: I don't understand the close votes here. I interpret them as saying "asking about notation is not allowed here". Possibly those who voted to close the question could therefore have helped the OP by suggesting what they should have done to solve their problem instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the collection of sets
$$\{n+p\mathbb Z\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$$
which forms a group $(G,+_G)$ with the group operation “$+_G$” defined by
$$(n+p\mathbb Z)+_G (m+p\mathbb Z)=(n+m)+p\mathbb Z$$

Recall that
$$p\mathbb Z=\{\ldots, -2p,-p,0,p,2p,\ldots\}$$
and that

$$n+p\mathbb Z=\{\ldots, n-2p,n-p,n,n+p,n+2p,\ldots\}$$

For a given positive integer $p$, this group consists of exactly $p$ distinct elements. For example, consider $p=3$. Then
$$0+3\mathbb Z=\{\ldots,-6,-3,0,3,6,\ldots\}$$

$$1+3\mathbb Z=\{\ldots,-5,-2,1,4,7,\ldots\}$$

$$2+3\mathbb Z=\{\ldots,-4,-1,2,5,8,\ldots\}$$
After this, they repeat:
$$3+3\mathbb Z=\{\ldots,-3,0,3,6,9,\ldots\}=0+3\mathbb Z$$

$$4+3\mathbb Z=\{\ldots,-2,1,4,7,10,\ldots\}=1+3\mathbb Z$$

etc., so this group contains three elements:
$$\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z=\{3 \mathbb Z,1+ 3\mathbb Z,2+ 3\mathbb Z\}.$$

A standard exercise is to show that the group operation is well-defined in the sense that the particular representations of the elements (e.g., $1+ 3\mathbb Z$ vs $4 + 3\mathbb Z$) still gives the same result when performing the group addition.